# PHP: Filling up an array with a value up to a certain index?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to fill up an array with values? I have an array with 5 elements and I want to add the string "filler" to the end until 10 elements are filled.

I tried to find a suitable PHP function, but failed so far. Is there a function at all, or do I have to use a loop?

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with using a loop?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php seriously?

Comment: Nothing, but why reinvent the wheel if there is a function?

Comment: @user1856596 Especially since built-in functions are many times faster than manually iterating ^_^

Comment: "I need to fill array with values, what should I do? Search `fill array` in manual? No, it's better to ask on SO".

Comment: @ElonThan `array_fill` is not the correct function to use.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Maybe not, but it's good place to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in function [`array_pad`](http://php.net/array-pad) serves exactly this purpose.

```
$padded_array = array_pad($source_array,10,"filler");
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I only found array_fill, which was not the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
<?php
$a = array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>3,3=>4,4=>5);
$b = array_fill(5, 10, 'filler');
$c=array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);
print_r($c);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => filler [6] => filler [7] => filler [8] => filler [9] => filler [10] => filler [11] => filler [12] => filler [13] => filler [14] => filler )
```